# How to detect USB device insertion event in Windows 8?

Tags: windows, usb

I usually detect USB device insertion and removal event by monitor WM_DEVICECHANGE message.
In Windows XP, when USB insertion event happened, message is below:

```
WM_DEVICECHANGE
WParam = DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL, devType = DBT_DEVTYP_DEVICEINTERFACE

WM_DEVICECHANGE
WParam = DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL, devType = DBT_DEVTYP_VOLUME
```

But now I am using Windows 8.1, for the same event, message is below:

```
WM_DEVICECHANGE
WParam = **DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL**, devType = DBT_DEVTYP_DEVICEINTERFACE

WM_DEVICECHANGE
WParam = **DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE**, devType = DBT_DEVTYP_DEVICEINTERFACE

WM_DEVICECHANGE
WParam = DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL, devType = DBT_DEVTYP_DEVICEINTERFACE

WM_DEVICECHANGE
WParam = DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL, devType = DBT_DEVTYP_VOLUME
```

My question is:

1. Why the first 2 messages come here?
2. How can I detect USB device insertion event in Windows 8?

Comment: Were you able to get any information on the first arrival/removal? This could be a difference in the OS or device enumeration. Since the first two (actually three) have nothing to do with a volume your code should still work to find the arrival message for the volume, and anything outside of that you should be able to ignore.

Comment: I am afraid no more information can get from the first arrival/removal event, seems both are similar to the normal event. maybe I can queue them and handle with a little bit delay to ensure detecting both of them because of the small delta time. My code should handle arrival/removal event in different function, and this strange event sequence really bother me :(

Answer (score 0):

The first two messages, `DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL` and `DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE` are generated by the system when a USB device is attached to and removed from it. By listening for these messages, your code can have 'plug-and-play' functionality: when a new devices is attached, do something; when it's removed do something else... I don't know that Win 8 is any different from previous versions, but there are several example of how to go about detecting USB 'device change' events given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26148141/handling-windows-usb-events/26167120#26167120), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16245706/check-for-device-change-add-remove-events) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2061167/how-to-receive-the-windows-messages-without-a-windows-form/2061741#2061741).

My solution is as follows, but essentially you cannot get away from listening for `WM_DEVICECHANGE` messages and for that you need a `WinForms` component wherein you override `WndProc()`. The MSDN article on "Device Management" is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363224%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
As you'll see, its all unmanaged code.

```c#
#pragma once

#include <Windows.h>    // Declares required datatypes.
#include <Dbt.h>        // Required for WM_DEVICECHANGE messages.
#include <initguid.h>   // Required for DEFINE_GUID definition (see below).

namespace USBComms 
{
    using namespace System;
    using namespace System::Runtime::InteropServices;
    using namespace System::Windows;
    using namespace System::Windows::Forms;

    // This function is required for receieving WM_DEVICECHANGE messages.
    // Note: name is remapped "RegisterDeviceNotificationUM"
    [DllImport("user32.dll" , CharSet = CharSet::Unicode, EntryPoint="RegisterDeviceNotification")]                 
    extern "C" HDEVNOTIFY WINAPI RegisterDeviceNotificationUM(
        HANDLE hRecipient,
        LPVOID NotificationFilter,
        DWORD Flags);

    // Generic guid for usb devices (see e.g. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff545972%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).
    // Note: GUIDs are device and OS specific and may require modification. Using the wrong guid will cause notification to fail.
    // You may have to tinker with your device to find the appropriate GUID. "hid.dll" has a function `HidD_GetHidGuid' that returns
    // "the device interfaceGUID for HIDClass devices" (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff538924%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).
    // However, testing revealed it does not always return a useful value. The GUID_DEVINTERFACE_USB_DEVICE value, defined as
    // {A5DCBF10-6530-11D2-901F-00C04FB951ED}, has worked with cell phones, thumb drives, etc. For more info, see e.g.
    // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff553426%28v=vs.85%29.aspx. 
    DEFINE_GUID(GUID_DEVINTERFACE_USB_DEVICE, 0xA5DCBF10L, 0x6530, 0x11D2, 0x90, 0x1F, 0x00, 0xC0, 0x4F, 0xB9, 0x51, 0xED);

    /// <summary>
    /// Declare a delegate for the notification event handler.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">The object where the event handler is attached.</param>
    /// <param name="e">The event data.</param>
    public delegate void NotificationEventHandler(Object^ sender, EventArgs^ e);

    /// <summary>
    /// Class that generetaes USB Device Change notification events.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// A Form is not necessary. Any type wherein you can override WndProc() can be used.
    /// </remarks>
    public ref class EventNotifier : public Control
    {
    private:
        /// <summary>
        /// Raises the NotificationEvent.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="e">The event data.</param>
        void RaiseNotificationEvent(EventArgs^ e) {
            NotificationEvent(this, e);
        }

    protected:
        /// <summary>
        /// Overrides the base class WndProc method.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="message">The Windows Message to process. </param>
        /// <remarks>
        /// This method receives Windows Messages (WM_xxxxxxxxxx) and
        /// raises our NotificationEvent as appropriate. Here you should
        /// add any message filtering (e.g. for the WM_DEVICECHANGE) and
        /// preprocessing before raising the event (or not).
        /// </remarks>
        virtual void WndProc(Message% message) override {
            if(message.Msg == WM_DEVICECHANGE)
            {
                RaiseNotificationEvent(EventArgs::Empty);
            }
            __super::WndProc(message);
        }

    public:
        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a new instance of the EventNotifier class.
        /// </summary>
        EventNotifier(void) {
            RequestNotifications(this->Handle); // Register ourselves as the Windows Message processor.
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Registers an object, identified by the handle, for
        /// Windows WM_DEVICECHANGE messages.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="handle">The object's handle.</param>
        bool RequestNotifications(IntPtr handle) {
            DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE NotificationFilter;

            ZeroMemory(&NotificationFilter, sizeof(NotificationFilter));
            NotificationFilter.dbcc_devicetype = DBT_DEVTYP_DEVICEINTERFACE;
            NotificationFilter.dbcc_size = sizeof(DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE);
            NotificationFilter.dbcc_reserved = 0;
            NotificationFilter.dbcc_classguid = GUID_DEVINTERFACE_USB_DEVICE;
            return RegisterDeviceNotificationUM((HANDLE)handle, &NotificationFilter, DEVICE_NOTIFY_WINDOW_HANDLE) != NULL;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Defines the notification event.
        /// </summary>
        virtual event NotificationEventHandler^ NotificationEvent;
    };
}
```

Then, in the 'receiver' (the object that subscribes to and consumes our `NotificationEvent`, all you have to do is:

```c#
void Receiver::SomeFunction(void)
{
    USBComms::EventNotifier usb = gcnew USBComms::EventNotifier();

    usb->NotificationEvent += gcnew USBComms::NotificationEventHandler(this, &Receiver::USBEvent);
}

void Receiver::USBEvent(Object^ sender, EventArgs^ e)
{
    // Handle the event notification as appropriate.
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but the solution is only worked on normal case. I have tested some machines running win8 and not only my machine has such duplicate message. maybe this is a bug?