# Handling Windows USB events

Tags: .net, windows, usb, eventhandler

I created a generic USB HID comms driver capable of monitoring USB events and sending/receiving data packets to and from devices. I've been using it successfully since my `WinForms` days as much of the code was culled from MSDN and implemented very similarly to the way suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16245706/check-for-device-change-add-remove-events). My question is: The examples I see continue to rely on what seem to be the old "Windows Messaging" architecture, i.e. `System.Runtime.InteropServices`, WM_xxxxxxx type messages, registering/handling these in a purely `C# WPF` app with `HwndHandler`, overriding `WndProc`, etc. I was wondering is there not a way to handle USB events using a more modern, event-driven approach, say with `delegates`, subscribing to `EventHandlers`, etc? Even [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/624367/how-to-handle-wndproc-messages-in-wpf) SO posts suggest refraining from using such archaic methods and I imagine there must be a solution for USB events as well. Thanx.

Comment: It is a bit like complaining that your brand new car has a combustion engine that was invented a hundred years ago.  The idea is old and solid and has a *lot* of infrastructure that support it, there just hasn't been anything compelling enough to replace it.  Anything can be wrapped to fit the paradigm *du jour*, its what most of the .NET Framework does.  Just not *that* detail.  Just don't do it yourself, take [somebody else's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2061741/17034).  With the obvious risk that you don't like that flavor either :)

Comment: Not really complaining, just thought I'd missed something and was still doing it the hundred-year-old-way when there was a today-way. Thanx for the link, I'll take a look.

Comment: Hans, I did look at "somebody else's" post and I already have something like that. I was just trying to get rid of the Windoze messaging stuff. Mine's a little different, doesn't rely on extra threading and dispenses with having to put the `OnSourceInitialized` and `WndProc` stuff in your "receiver" `Window`. I'll post the working parts here and link to "somebody else's". BTW, I'm not averse to using legacy code. I use the `WinForms PropertyGrid` in my stuff all the time and just write custom `TypeConverters` and `UIEditors`. The `PropertyGrid` is robust, proven and, I've found no substitute.

Comment: Well, I did as I said, posted an answer and a linked to "somebody elses" answer. Unfortunately, "somebody else" must've had a bad hair day. First I got a bunch of auto-generated comments (the wording was identical) telling me not to "link" answers and post the whole answer there. When I asked for clarification and to research my answer to see if it was even relevant, I received none (I don't think it was even read). Then I did as suggested and posted this answer on "somebody else's" question. I got down-voted and blocked. All this on my first attempt at contributing. What kind site is SO?

Answer (score 1):

After doing a bit of research, it seems that Windows messaging is a necessary part of handling USB Device Change notifications. I have a working usb comms driver class which includes a simple implementation. This solution consists of two parts, 1) the `EventNotifier` class, which generates the events and 2) the 'receiver', which subscribes to the events (i.e. a client that gets notified of USB events). The sample code is C++/CLI and although I don't subscribe to the practice of putting executable code in header files, for the sake of brevity, I do so here.

```c#
#pragma once

#include <Windows.h>    // Declares required datatypes.
#include <Dbt.h>        // Required for WM_DEVICECHANGE messages.
#include <initguid.h>   // Required for DEFINE_GUID definition (see below).

namespace USBComms 
{
    using namespace System;
    using namespace System::Runtime::InteropServices;
    using namespace System::Windows;
    using namespace System::Windows::Forms;

    // This function is required for receieving WM_DEVICECHANGE messages.
    // Note: name is remapped "RegisterDeviceNotificationUM"
    [DllImport("user32.dll" , CharSet = CharSet::Unicode, EntryPoint="RegisterDeviceNotification")]                 
    extern "C" HDEVNOTIFY WINAPI RegisterDeviceNotificationUM(
        HANDLE hRecipient,
        LPVOID NotificationFilter,
        DWORD Flags);

    // Generic guid for usb devices (see e.g. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff545972%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).
    // Note: GUIDs are device and OS specific and may require modification. Using the wrong guid will cause notification to fail.
    // You may have to tinker with your device to find the appropriate GUID. "hid.dll" has a function `HidD_GetHidGuid' that returns
    // "the device interfaceGUID for HIDClass devices" (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff538924%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).
    // However, testing revealed it does not always return a useful value. The GUID_DEVINTERFACE_USB_DEVICE value, defined as
    // {A5DCBF10-6530-11D2-901F-00C04FB951ED}, has worked with cell phones, thumb drives, etc. For more info, see e.g.
    // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff553426%28v=vs.85%29.aspx. 
    DEFINE_GUID(GUID_DEVINTERFACE_USB_DEVICE, 0xA5DCBF10L, 0x6530, 0x11D2, 0x90, 0x1F, 0x00, 0xC0, 0x4F, 0xB9, 0x51, 0xED);

    /// <summary>
    /// Declare a delegate for the notification event handler.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">The object where the event handler is attached.</param>
    /// <param name="e">The event data.</param>
    public delegate void NotificationEventHandler(Object^ sender, EventArgs^ e);

    /// <summary>
    /// Class that generetaes USB Device Change notification events.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// A Form is not necessary. Any type wherein you can override WndProc() can be used.
    /// </remarks>
    public ref class EventNotifier : public Control
    {
    private:
        /// <summary>
        /// Raises the NotificationEvent.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="e">The event data.</param>
        void RaiseNotificationEvent(EventArgs^ e) {
            NotificationEvent(this, e);
        }

    protected:
        /// <summary>
        /// Overrides the base class WndProc method.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="message">The Windows Message to process. </param>
        /// <remarks>
        /// This method receives Windows Messages (WM_xxxxxxxxxx) and
        /// raises our NotificationEvent as appropriate. Here you should
        /// add any message filtering (e.g. for the WM_DEVICECHANGE) and
        /// preprocessing before raising the event (or not).
        /// </remarks>
        virtual void WndProc(Message% message) override {
            if(message.Msg == WM_DEVICECHANGE)
            {
                RaiseNotificationEvent(EventArgs::Empty);
            }
            __super::WndProc(message);
        }

    public:
        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a new instance of the EventNotifier class.
        /// </summary>
        EventNotifier(void) {
            RequestNotifications(this->Handle); // Register ourselves as the Windows Message processor.
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Registers an object, identified by the handle, for
        /// Windows WM_DEVICECHANGE messages.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="handle">The object's handle.</param>
        void RequestNotifications(IntPtr handle) {
            GUID InterfaceClassGuid = GUID_DEVINTERFACE_USB_DEVICE;
            DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE MyDeviceBroadcastHeader;

            MyDeviceBroadcastHeader.dbcc_devicetype = DBT_DEVTYP_DEVICEINTERFACE;
            MyDeviceBroadcastHeader.dbcc_size = sizeof(DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE);
            MyDeviceBroadcastHeader.dbcc_reserved = 0;
            MyDeviceBroadcastHeader.dbcc_classguid = InterfaceClassGuid;
            RegisterDeviceNotificationUM((HANDLE)handle, &MyDeviceBroadcastHeader, DEVICE_NOTIFY_WINDOW_HANDLE);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Defines the notification event.
        /// </summary>
        virtual event NotificationEventHandler^ NotificationEvent;
    };
}
```

Then, in the 'receiver' (the object that subscribes to and consumes our `NotificationEvent`, all you have to do is:

```c#
void Receiver::SomeFunction(void)
{
    USBComms::EventNotifier usb = gcnew USBComms::EventNotifier();

    usb->NotificationEvent += gcnew USBComms::NotificationEventHandler(this, &Receiver::USBEvent);
}

void Receiver::USBEvent(Object^ sender, EventArgs^ e)
{
    // Handle the event notification as appropriate.
}
```