# passing delegate in to C++ method for a window

Tags: c#, c++, delegates, pinvoke

So I've been contemplating if it is possible to use a delegate in to a PInvoke signature when the signature calls for a handle to a window (Such as in `AddClipboardFormatListener(IntPtr hwnd)`).

I ask because essentially all it does is makes a call to said windows HwnProc method....So what if I made a delegate like this:

```
public delegate IntPtr MainWindowProc(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, 
                IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
```

and changed `AddClipboardFormatListener` to look like this instead:

```
AddClipboardFormatListener(MainWindowProc theDelegate)
```

I got the idea from `SetWindowsHookEx` where I made a delegate for the callback for the second parameter. I'm fixing to wire up a test for this right now, so I might be answering my own question... but then I got to thinking they don't call the method, they get the instance and call he method.. So maybe I'd have to do something like

```
public interface ICanReadWindows
{
    IntPtr MainWindowProc(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled);
}
```

and pass that in to `AddClipboardFormatListener`??? I'm not super familiar with how that all plays together so I was hoping to pick peoples brains (such as Hans)

Thank you

Comment: No, you need a window and a message loop.  The window already takes care of the delegate.  Pass the window's handle to the function.  Boilerplate code [is here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2061741/17034), just change the WndProc() override.