# Hook minimize event of third party application

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, hook, pinvoke

I have following hook class:

```
public sealed class Hook : IDisposable
{
    public delegate void Win32Event(IntPtr hWnd);

    #region Windows API

    private const uint WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT = 0x0000;


    [DllImport("User32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr SetWinEventHook(
        uint eventMin,
        uint eventMax,
        IntPtr hmodWinEventProc,
        WinEventDelegate lpfnWinEventProc,
        uint idProcess,
        uint idThread,
        uint dwFlags);


    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool UnhookWinEvent(
        IntPtr hWinEventHook
        );

    private enum SystemEvents : uint
    {
        EVENT_OBJECT_CREATE = 0x8000,
        EVENT_OBJECT_DESTROY = 0x8001,
        EVENT_SYSTEM_MINIMIZESTART = 0x0016,
        EVENT_SYSTEM_MINIMIZEEND = 0x0017,
        EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND = 0x0003
    }

    private delegate void WinEventDelegate(
        IntPtr hWinEventHook,
        uint eventType,
        IntPtr hWnd,
        int idObject,
        int idChild,
        uint dwEventThread,
        uint dwmsEventTime);

    #endregion

    public Win32Event OnWindowCreate = delegate { };
    public Win32Event OnWindowDestroy = delegate { };
    public Win32Event OnWindowForegroundChanged = delegate { };
    public Win32Event OnWindowMinimizeEnd = delegate { };
    public Win32Event OnWindowMinimizeStart = delegate { };
    private IntPtr pHook;
    private bool _disposed;


    public Hook(IntPtr hWnd)
    {
        pHook = SetWinEventHook((uint) SystemEvents.EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND,
                                (uint) SystemEvents.EVENT_OBJECT_DESTROY,
                                hWnd,
                                WinEvent,
                                0,
                                0,
                                WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT
            );
        if (IntPtr.Zero.Equals(pHook))
            throw new Win32Exception();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
    }


    private void WinEvent(IntPtr hWinEventHook, uint eventType, IntPtr hWnd, int idObject, int idChild,
                          uint dwEventThread, uint dwmsEventTime)
    {
        switch ((SystemEvents) eventType)
        {
            case SystemEvents.EVENT_OBJECT_DESTROY:
                OnWindowDestroy(hWnd);
                break;

            case SystemEvents.EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND:
                OnWindowForegroundChanged(hWnd);
                break;

            case SystemEvents.EVENT_SYSTEM_MINIMIZESTART:
                OnWindowMinimizeStart(hWnd);
                break;

            case SystemEvents.EVENT_SYSTEM_MINIMIZEEND:
                OnWindowMinimizeEnd(hWnd);
                break;

            case SystemEvents.EVENT_OBJECT_CREATE:
                OnWindowCreate(hWnd);
                break;
        }
    }


    ~Hook()
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }

    private void Dispose(bool manual)
    {
        if (_disposed)
            return;
        if (!IntPtr.Zero.Equals(pHook))
            UnhookWinEvent(pHook);

        pHook = IntPtr.Zero;
        OnWindowCreate = null;
        OnWindowDestroy = null;
        OnWindowForegroundChanged = null;
        OnWindowMinimizeStart = null;
        OnWindowMinimizeEnd = null;
        _disposed = true;

        if (manual)
        {
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }
    }
}
```

But when I use it nothing happens:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var process = Process.GetProcessesByName("Notepad")[0];
        var hook = new Hook(process.MainWindowHandle);
        hook.OnWindowMinimizeStart += wnd => Console.WriteLine("Minimized at {0}", DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString());
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

what am I doing wrong here? It seems that everything is OK.

Comment: Your calling this from a Console application however *"The client thread that calls SetWinEventHook must have a message loop in order to receive events."*  Stick it in a forms app and it would work fine.

Comment: You're right. Changing to winforms worked to me. Unfortunly it seems that it's not possible to run it in console application.

Comment: Something like `System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(new System.Windows.Forms.Form());` after the hook call in the console app would work to setup the loop

Comment: The operating system doesn't care that you created a console mode app, it only cares that you dedicate a thread to pumping the message loop.  Sample code [is here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2061741/17034).