# How can I raise an event when a new item is added to Devices and Printers?

Tags: c#, .net, events, usb, device-detection

**Background:**

> I'm using a third-party library to read a smart card used as an ID
>   card.
>
> This library only supports a method to read the card. It doesn't throw
>   events when the card is inserted into the reader. As a result,
>   currently, I can only have the card read when a button is clicked. I
>   want to remove this requirement of clicking.

**Requirement:**

> When the ID card is inserted into the reader, the software
>   automatically adds an item to "Devices and Printers" called "ID Card". How
>   can I get a notification when this item is added?

**Current findings:**

> [This excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/620144/detecting-usb-drive-insertion-and-removal-using-windows-service-and-c-sharp) successfully triggers an event when the USB
>   reader is inserted into the computer. It does not, however, trigger an
>   event when the card is inserted into the reader (even though it
>   somehow appears in the "Devices and Printers" list.
>
> [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16245706/check-for-device-change-add-remove-events) lists all the USB devices connected to the computer.
>   It somehow lists more devices than are connected to the computer (8
>   when there are only 3 devices + the card). It also does not detect the
>   card - the number remains the same whether or not the card is inserted
>   into the reader.

How can I read this "Devices and Printers" list? And how can I detect when a new item is added to this list?

Comment: You have to listen for the Plug and Play event.  Not that easy to do in C#, the framework is no support at all for the SetupAPI.  Use http://stackoverflow.com/a/2061741/17034

Comment: Thank you! This worked for me by instead detecting when the smart card got added to "Smart Cards" under devices - I should have thought of that before the "Devices and Printers" route. Should I close this as a duplicate (not sure - as this may not be considered a duplicate) or will you post your comment as the answer?