# "COM object that has been separated from its underlying RCW cannot be used." with static WMI event

Tags: c#, static, com, wmi

I am trying to implement an USB device notifier which  has static events when e.g. a USB device is unpugged. I tried this with a class like the following:

```
public static class WmiUsbNotifier
{
    private static ManagementEventWatcher watcherDetach;

    public static event EventHandler<EventArgs<WmiDeviceNotifyEventArgs>> DeviceNotify;

    public static void Initialize()
    {
        var detachQuery = new WqlEventQuery("SELECT * FROM __InstanceDeletionEvent WITHIN 1 WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_USBControllerDevice'");
        watcherDetach = new ManagementEventWatcher();
        watcherDetach.EventArrived += ManagementEventWatcher_Detaching;
        watcherDetach.Query = detachQuery;
        watcherDetach.Start();
    }
    public static void ShutDown()
    {
        watcherDetach?.Stop();
        watcherDetach?.Dispose();
        watcherDetach = null;
    }

    private static void ManagementEventWatcher_Detaching(object sender, EventArrivedEventArgs e)
    {
        var targetInstance = (ManagementBaseObject)e.NewEvent.Properties["TargetInstance"].Value;
        var id = targetInstance.Properties["Dependent"].Value.ToString();
        DeviceNotify?.Invoke(watcherDetach, new WmiDeviceNotifyEventArgs(EventType.DeviceRemoveComplete, id));
    }
}
```

This works fine and everything is well **IF** I call `ShutDown()` before closing my app (e.g. in `OnExit` of my WPF App). But if I do not call that I get the following error when closing my app:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.InvalidComObjectException' occurred in System.Management.dll
>
> Additional information: COM object that has been separated from its underlying RCW cannot be used.

Now I would like to avoid this WITHOUT the need to "externally call ShutDown()", because this is part of a library which can be used by others and the chances are high the will forget to call that method in their apps.

I tried already calling it in `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DomainUnload`, but the exception occures before that. I also tried making the class above not static and adding a finalizer/IDisposable and setting an instance as a static property of another class, but there the finalizer is also called to late.

Is there any way to call the `ShutDown()` method "automatically" before this exception occurs?
Or is there a way to catch and swallow exactly this exception? (As it happens when shutting down it can be ignored anyway)

Comment: Can you listen to the `Application.Exit` event by reflection?

Comment: @sweerpotato: Isn't that only a WinForms event? What about Console/WPF/COM/...? But I will check...

Comment: The fatal mistake is in the ManagementEventWatcher's finalizer, it calls Stop().  And Stop() uses ReleaseComObject(), kaboom when the COM object is already finalized.  This bug is taking out [Microsoft's own products as well](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/2810689/ssms-crashes-on-shutdown-then-restarts).  No simple fix here, the library user has to help.  Consider [not using System.Management](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2061741/17034).

Comment: @HansPassant: Thanks for your input. I will try your solution. I previously used LibUSB.NET's device notifier with such a "invisible form", but had a case where it did not work...